# Eclipse annotation processing not finding class on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, velocity, annotation-processing

We use Eclipse Annotation processing with the Velocity code generation framework.
A while ago, we updated all our code and builds to use Java 11 - and didn't notice that the code generation no longer worked. (we haven't need to change any of the generated code for a while.)

After updating various jars and rebuilding the Eclipse plugin, it's trying to call our code generation processor - but it's getting a NoClassDefFound error for the class `DataModelClassWrapper`.  That should be easy to resolve, but the jar with that class is already in the project classpath, and in the Eclipse annotation FactoryPath.  I've verified that the .class is in the .jar file as well.  Also the `VelocityCodeGenProcessor` class (where the error comes from) is in the same jar and package as the `DataModelClassWrapper`.

Note that we use the "plugin" by extracting the .jar from it, and adding that to the classpath of our project and annotation factory path.

At this point I suspect that either I'm missing something obvious, or I've found some obscure corner-problem case. (most likely the former)

```
eclipse.buildId=4.16.0.I20200604-0540
java.version=11.0.7
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core
Error
Wed Jul 08 17:13:06 PDT 2020
Exception thrown by Java annotation processor com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.VelocityCodeGenProcessor@2ccc9525

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.DataModelClassWrapper
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotationsInternal(Compiler.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.DataModelClassWrapper
    at com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.DataModel.getWrapped(DataModel.java:35)
    at com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.DataModel.doAnalysis(DataModel.java:90)
    at com.metrixsoftware.build.annotationProcessor.velocityCodeGen.VelocityCodeGenProcessor.process(VelocityCodeGenProcessor.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:142)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but an answer.
Cleaned and rebuilt AGAIN, and the exception changed.  Note that the specific class being reported as Not Found has varied a few times - with no code changes.
Now it was complaining about another class (PropertiesUtil from log4j, which was in the classpath) not being found.  But this one was referenced from the "DataModelClassWrapper" which was the class it couldn't find previously.
Checked DataModelClassWrapper, and found it had an unused field declaring a log4j Logger that was never used.  So I deleted it.
Then, all of a sudden, everything started working.

I REALLY REALLY HATE this kind of "fix".  It doesn't really explain what was wrong, or what changed to fix it.